# Do keyboard apps which are enabled but not selected have access to input text?

Tags: security, keyboard, privacy

I installed a keyboard app on Android 6 and when enabling it, the OS showed a warning that the keyboard app has access to input text.

Since the warning appeared on enabling, not selecting, this question appeared: do keyboard apps which are enabled but not selected have access to input text? If it is another way in other Android versions, feel free to describe that, as a part of the answer.

Comment: I assume this warning comes because you can select a different keyboard app for each regular app (from the list of enabled keyboard apps). This means that every enabled app can be used at any time.

Comment: i have copied this to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795934/in-android-do-keyboard-apps-which-are-enabled-but-not-selected-have-access-to-i